# How to disable 24-hour format in UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, iphone

i want to disable 24 - clock format in UIDatePicker , My requirement is to show only AM/PM format date picker. If user enable the 24-hour Time in the phone settings. my date Picker is Showing 24 - hour format, i want force it to show 12 - hour format. Please suggest me.

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Date format depends of your device locale settings.

Although it's not recommended in most cases, you can override locale settings:

For example this gives you 24h format:

`self.datePicker.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_GB"];`

and this 12h format with PM/AM

`self.datePicker.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];`

Comment: @nikey you can set either [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_GB"] for 24 hour format or set [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"] for 12 hour format with AM/PM option.

If you can set date picker with timer mode, then 12 hour format with AM/PM is the default format.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

We can Customise only current date will be in 24hrs format if user set means as per iOS device settings .. Otherwise we can set like this

```
NSDate *currDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currDate];

_todayDateLbl.text=dateString;
#pragma get current time

dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"hh:mm a";
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
NSLog(@"The Current Time is %@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:currDate]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You just cannot set the 12/24 format.

It depends on user's setting on their iOS device.

Comment: you mean that we cannot customize the date picker.

Comment: no we can't. UIDatePicker is related to system configure. Apple has to do this to ensure user's experience

Answer (score 1):

Depends on locale, but you could build your own date picker.

Answer (score 1):

For 24 hr format try...

```
 NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"NL"];
 [self.datePicker setLocale:locale];
```

Comment: He wants to disable it, not enable it.