# Set minimum and maximum date AND TIME in UIDatePicker in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uikit, uidatepicker

I have to set min and max dates AND time in date picker which I achieved with following properties:

```
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.dateAndTime

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = self.dateFormat
let minDate = dateFormatter.date(from: self.fromDate) //Day before yesterday
let maxDate = dateFormatter.date(from: self.toDate) //Yesterday

datePicker.minimumDate = minDate
datePicker.maximumDate = maxDate
```

However, I am also showing Time Picker with this, but it is limiting to only `00:00` value after changing time or date.

How do I set **min** time as `00:00` for 24-hrs time and `12:00 am` for 12-hrs time? (Same for **max** time as `23:59` and `11:59 pm`)

[image]

Comment: max time 11:59 or 12:59?. what you need to achieve?

Comment: @Arasuvel, 11:59 , mistake! Updating question

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33167454/4061501)

Comment: You can use date components to derive the date , by specifying the hours and minutes.Check this out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494174/minimum-and-maximum-date-in-uidatepicker/10494471

Comment: @LalKrishna , yes, I am setting Locale as well, it won't affect the scenario.